# libreoffice writer does not show "File", "Edit", etc. in standard toolbar/taskbar

Tags: libreoffice

It shows some of the captions like "Help".

I tried to uninstall using `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*` and then reinstall first using command prompt and then using ubuntu software centre. It did not work. Now I have uninstalled it. But this is a very important software as Abiword cannot work with .docx as efficiently as libreoffice.

Problem started when I tried to install themes and icons with noobslab.com and removed the theme and icons afterwards along with gnome tweak tool. I also cleaned the computer with gnome tweak tool's janitor.

Please Help!

Comment: Can you try reinstalling the themes using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to delete configuration folder on your home directory? It persists even when you uninstall.

Complete path is:

```
/home/$USER/.config/libreoffice
```

where `$USER` is your account name

Try to delete that folder and reinstall.